# Git - compare local and remote without fetching first?

Tags: git, compare

I've searched around and found no answer to this question.

I have an app running on Heroku. 
From my local machine I typically implement and just:

```
git add .
git commit -m "whatever change, I know I can add and commit at the same time..."
git push <the-heroku-repo>
```

Then it goes up and the master branch in the Heroku app is updated. So far so good.

Now. I want to have another machine that will automatically make a pull from the Heroku repo and update itself.

So i do that with:

```
git clone <the-heroku-repo>
```

That gets me the app and I can see the git config with this:

```
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
remote.origin.url=git@heroku.com:theapp.git
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
```

To update this new repo I can do just a pull:

```
git pull origin
```

Or I could fetch and merge:

```
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

MY QUESTION

Between the above fetch and merge I can check what are the changes by doing:

```
git log -p master..origin/master
```

Is there a way to find the differences between the local master branch and the latest version in the remote Heroku repo without fetching before? Just compare the local and remote and see the changes. I just can't find the proper way.

Thanks.

Comment: without fetching, you won't know anything update from the remote repo

Comment: I'm interested in what the problem is with doing `git fetch origin` before the `git log`?

Comment: Maybe the problem is me, based on the definition of the fetch command: "git fetch download new branches and data from a remote repository". Imagine that based on some output of the comparison I would decide that I don't want to fetch and merge that changes. Why would I use bandwidth and polute the repository with something that is not needed. Again, maybe the problem is me. Just trying to save a call or resources if possible by knowing before hand the existing changes.

Comment: You're not "polluting the repository" by doing a fetch as it doesn't affect your local repository. If you're concerned about `git`ting branches you don't care about, you can specify only master: `git fetch origin master`. Retrieving `master` is never wasted if you expect to ever merge/rebase and submit changes upstream.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Although you can get some summary information about the branches in the `origin` repository using:

```
git remote show origin
```

... you do need to fetch the branches from `origin` into your repository somehow in order to compare them.  This is what `git fetch` does.  When you run `git fetch origin`, it will by default only update the so-called "remote-tracking branches" such as `origin/master`.  These just store where the corresponding branch was at in `origin` the last time you fetched.  All your local branches that you've been working on are unaffected by the `git fetch`.  So, it's safe to do:

```
git fetch origin
git log -p master..origin/master
```

... and then if you're happy with that, you can merge from or rebase onto `origin/master`.

---

I would encourage you not to worry about the resources (either disk space or bandwidth) involved in the `git fetch origin` command.  git efficiently sends just the objects that are necessary to complete the remote-tracking branches that are being updated, and unless you have unusually large files stored with your source code, this shouldn't make much of a difference.  In addition, it's frequently useful to have the complete history of the branches from the other repository available even if you don't plan to use them, for example so you can examine that development history.

Comment: Thanks for those quick comments and answer. So it was me :-)

Comment: I was using PULL which was serving me well, but then I read a billion times to prefer fetch/merge over it so I started using it. It works fine, but it took me a while to realize that GIT fetch fetches all remote branches into a "temp space" and you are the first one to say its name "remote-tracking branches". I really coudn't understad where the fetched data was going because it's not until merge that it is inside of your repository. Thanks