# Git diff between clone and remote if you can't fetch?

Tags: git

I have a scenario where I have clones of my repository periodically created into a read-only directory archival purposes.

I have some script that contextually needs to run from within the cloned directory and I'm trying to find some way to check whether there exists a newer version of some file than what is in the cloned directory.

I am a relatively new git user, but every way I can think to do this seems to be based on the idea of at least being able to do a fetch to get the commit history since the clone was made. I can't do that though since the clone dir is read-only.

Coming from other CM systems I keep thinking there must be some way for me to get the ID of the latest revision of the file from the remote and compare it to the clone that does not rely on fetching first but have had no success.

I've referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7571047/git-compare-local-and-remote-without-fetching-first) post but the only answer appears to be that there is no alternative to fetching.

Comment: It appears to me, that it is indeed not possible with git itself to access remote refs without fetching. Please explain in more detail what exactly your scenario is (your ultimate goal so to say). Currently I could think of 3 options: another application that can talk to the remote (supports gits protocol). Your remote itself (if it is something like GitHub, Stash or GitLab) might have an API that enables you to request such info. You could move the .git directory to a non-read-only location and only leave the working copy on the read-only directory.

Comment: Is the original repository local or remote? (do you have to access the network?)

Comment: The intent of the script is to compare the read-only cloned repository to a review log and assert whether or not cloned file versions are newer than the last reviewed. The review log contains the tag name of the last reviewed version. The alternative approach I've settled on is to simply assert that the files are at least different by diffing the file from the current tag to the last reviewed tag without definitively stating that one is newer than the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot get an actual diff directly.

You *can* see if you're up to date, and if not, use the system that has the *newer* stuff—which by definition is the system that is *not* read-only—to provide the diff, since the older version must<sup>1</sup> be in the newer version's history.

To get a complete diff of the newer version vs the older one, run this command on the newer system:

```
$ git diff <old-commit-sha1> <new-commit-sha1>
```

To limit this diff to a single path (and hence check whether that path needs updating):

```
$ git diff <old-sha1> <new-sha1> -- <path>
```

If the system that is not read-only does not permit you to run enough commands to get it to produce the desired diff, you need a third place (system or git repository) in which you can produce this diff, by cloning the more-advanced repository, doing the diff using the clone (which has everything needed), then optionally deleting this clone.  If you can keep this clone around and keep it read/write, you'll be in much better shape for the *next* run of this same task.  Furthermore, you'll find that you can discard the read-only clone entirely, since you're just using it for one thing at this point: you are using it to keep the SHA-1 of the previous commit.

All you need is the old commit's SHA-1 ID, because the newer system has the complete history (but see footnote 1 again).  Furthermore, this is what tags are for: tags refer to a particular commit,<sup>2</sup> giving a human-readable name for what is otherwise just a big ugly SHA-1.  (Well, annotated tags offer you a bit more than just a name.  In particular they let you provide a PGP signature saying that you are endorsing that particular SHA-1 as well.)

#### OK, but how do you see if you're up to date?

To do this, you *must* have at least *some* access to the read/write repository.  You then simply need to see what SHA-1 goes with one of their branches, compared to what SHA-1 goes with one of yours (whether it has the same name or not).

There's the human-readable version, `git show remote <remote-name>`, which will show you something like this:

```
$ git show remote origin
... [snip]
    master             pushes to master             (local out of date)
```

and the more script-able one needed to find actual SHA-1s:

```
$ git ls-remote origin
```

The second one produces a lot of detail, giving you everything by default; add `--heads`, `--tags`, and/or a specific reference to get just one item; for instance:

```
$ git ls-remote origin refs/heads/master
 <big ugly sha-1>   refs/heads/master
```

Compare this SHA-1 to your own SHA-1 for the same branch:

```
$ git rev-parse master
<big ugly sha-1>
```

If these are different, there are new commits in the not-read-only repository.  Note that these new commits *may not* affect some particular <path>s that you care about; to find out, you must work with a repository that has those commits, so that you can find the SHA-1(s) of the path(s) within the two commits that you care about.

For example:

```
$ git rev-parse master:.gitignore
50ac108339a8c7164e0620a074049ad03cb80aee
```

You can do this for specific revisions:

```
$ git rev-parse <sha-1>:.gitignore
```

but you must have the commits.

---

<sup>1</sup>This assumes whoever controls the read/write repository does not alter or delete some of it.  Any time you give control of your data to someone else, you make such an assumption, of course.  If you've memorized a particular SHA-1, the fact that it's a cryptographic signature means that you can test whether they've changed your data, but it's not sufficient on its own to recover it: you'd need some other clone(s) for that.

<sup>2</sup>A tag can refer directly to a tree or blob, or to another tag, rather than to a commit, but that's not the usual case.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation as it helps fill in some gaps in my understanding of Git as well as realize what I ideally wanted to do is not possible. Will proceed with an alternate approach.